# Filtering data based on timedelta between datetime values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm cleaning some data in pandas and trying to put the data into categories. Essentially, this is data from a call center.

I've done a lot of manipulation already and have a "bad" calling category. What I would like to do is split my "bad" dataframe into two separate dataframes: "bad" and "not so bad", respectively.

The most simple way I can logically segment these is to say that "bad" calling is still "not so bad" if the number was called multiple times. However, if the number was only called once it is a "bad" calling effort.

Sounds simple enough. However, the issue is that some numbers appear to have been called more than once when in actuality they are not. For example, the timestamp of two calls is 8:00:20 and 8:00:25. This is essentially a glitch in relaying the data (for whatever reason, of which there are likely many) but this is surely just one call. I dont want these calls going into the "not so bad" category.

My (relevant) data is of this form:

```
index   id1    id2     timestamp                       number
------|------|-------|-------------------------------|-------------
465     255    3644    2019-05-02 08:00:20.137000      1547856254
8736    255    3644    2019-05-02 08:00:25.145000      1547856254
62      87     912     2019-04-30 05:00:00.210000      2687892346
120     87     912     2019-04-29 11:00:00.030000      2687892346
```

To clarify, the timestamp column is dtype Timestamp.

The first two rows in the index should just be one row and in the "bad" calling dataframe. On the other hand, the last two rows are an example of something "not so bad" and should be put in that dataframe.

How can I go about this?

I think I need a logical mask based on the timestamp.

Basically a vectorized version of this pseudocode:

```
if (id1,id2,number) are the same for any number of rows:
    if the timestamps are within 20 seconds of each other:
        only keep the first row

if (id1,id2,number) are repeated:
    put in "not so bad" dataframe
else:
    put in "bad" dataframe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from pandas.compat import StringIO

print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""index,id1,id2,timestamp,number
465,255,3644,2019-05-02 08:00:20.137000,1547856254
8736,255,3644,2019-05-02 8:00:25,1547856254
8739,255,3644,2019-05-02 9:00:10,1547856254
8740,255,3644,2019-05-02 9:00:15,1547856254
8749,255,3644,2019-05-02 9:01:10,1547856254
8750,255,3644,2019-05-02 9:00:20,1547856254
8751,255,3644,2019-05-02 9:00:21,1547856254
8752,255,3644,2019-05-02 9:00:22,1547856254
62,87,912,2019-05-02 5:00:00,2687892346
120,87,912,2019-05-02 11:00:05,2687892346
120,87,912,2019-05-02 11:00:00,2687892346
""")

# prep dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",")
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.sort_values(['id1', 'id2', 'timestamp'], inplace=True)

# get timedeltas
df['timestamp_shift'] = df.groupby(['id1', 'id2', 'number']).shift()['timestamp']
df['time_delta'] = df['timestamp'] - df['timestamp_shift']
five_seconds = np.timedelta64(5,'s')

df['bad'] = df['time_delta'] <= five_seconds

print(df)
```

Produces

```
0.24.2
    index  id1   id2               timestamp      number         timestamp_shift      time_delta    bad
8      62   87   912 2019-05-02 05:00:00.000  2687892346                     NaT             NaT  False
10    120   87   912 2019-05-02 11:00:00.000  2687892346 2019-05-02 05:00:00.000        06:00:00  False
9     120   87   912 2019-05-02 11:00:05.000  2687892346 2019-05-02 11:00:00.000        00:00:05   True
0     465  255  3644 2019-05-02 08:00:20.137  1547856254                     NaT             NaT  False
1    8736  255  3644 2019-05-02 08:00:25.000  1547856254 2019-05-02 08:00:20.137 00:00:04.863000   True
2    8739  255  3644 2019-05-02 09:00:10.000  1547856254 2019-05-02 08:00:25.000        00:59:45  False
3    8740  255  3644 2019-05-02 09:00:15.000  1547856254 2019-05-02 09:00:10.000        00:00:05   True
5    8750  255  3644 2019-05-02 09:00:20.000  1547856254 2019-05-02 09:00:15.000        00:00:05   True
6    8751  255  3644 2019-05-02 09:00:21.000  1547856254 2019-05-02 09:00:20.000        00:00:01   True
7    8752  255  3644 2019-05-02 09:00:22.000  1547856254 2019-05-02 09:00:21.000        00:00:01   True
4    8749  255  3644 2019-05-02 09:01:10.000  1547856254 2019-05-02 09:00:22.000        00:00:48  False
```

Comment: Hi Rich, I think your answer is the best way to go about this I have seen as of yet, One note, you were correct to assume something is omitted. The actual timestamp looks like this: `2019-05-02 15:21:45.137000`. How will this affect the code?

Comment: Having a full `datetime64` for `timestamp` greatly simplifies the problem since datetime and timedeltas eliminate the need for working with computed seconds.  If this works for you, please feel free to accept my updated answer.  Also might want to update the Q subject to something like "Filtering data based on timedelta between datetime values"

Comment: The code above is good. But it actually only works for `n=2` so to speak. I.e., if a number repeats more than 2 times, the code breaks down. Take for example number 1547856254 being called at 8:00:20,8:00:25, and 9:00:10. In this case one of the 8:00 times and the 9:00 time should both be kept. As the code is now, however, only one of the 8:00 times is kept and 9:00 is dropped. I will change the question title. Good suggestion!

Comment: Updated. Prior code failed to sort.  However, it does work for n > 2, but the shortcoming is that if there are repeated calls, they are continually excluded until the same call stops happening for more than five seconds.  I left the intermediate columns in place so they can be seen.

Comment: I think this works perfectly. Appending a column as a flag helps a lot. Got it. Thanks a lot. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a groupby grouping with the minutes:

First I would drop the seconds:

```
    df["timestamp"] = df["timestamp"].map(lambda x: x.replace(second=0))
```

Here you have converted the time stamps from  8:00:20 to  8:00, if you wish you can keep the original values.

Then you can apply the groupby, keeping the first element:

```
    df.groupby(['timestamp', 'id1'], as_index=False).first()
```

You will keep the first element id1 in the timestamp list.

Good Luck!